# How do I read strings from a textfile in Linked List usings Java?

Tags: java, list, file-io

I don't remember how to get strings from a textfile.txt

I just have a two commands and then the name of the info

```
I = Insert
D = Delete
```

Example:

```
I Blue
I Red
D Blue
I Green
D Red
D Green
```

So one would be String command and the other String info

Any help??

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention it tells me to prompt the user to specify the name of the input file

Comment: Whats your question. how to read from a file? or how to process your commands?

Comment: How to read the file and get the commands from the txt file

Comment: Smells like homework. Maybe you should tag it as such?

Comment: It is HW, but this is just a small part of it, I just don't remember how to read txt files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little primitive but it works. It uses `Scanner` class and `StringTokenizer`. Of course, there could be many other ways to do it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Enter file name:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fname = input.nextLine();
    File file = new File(fname);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line);
            String command = tokens.nextToken();
            String info = tokens.nextToken();
            System.out.println("command = " + command + " info = " + info);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It was tested for the following data:

```
I Blue
I Red 
D Blue 
I Green
D Red 
D Green
```

Comment: @fgualda87: I've rewritten the code to match this requirement. It's a lot simpler now.

Comment: @Lukas thanks! I now need to add a method to check if the info is already in the list or not, I guess that would be the last line

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
 at FReader.main(Garage.java:19)

Comment: See my edit. Unfortunately, I have no idea why you're getting such exception (maybe you have some strange whitespace characters in your text file?)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I had some weird characters at the beginning of the file I did not see. It is working perfectly fine now. Thank you very much!